# vaadin 8 grid with column of Double datatype based on Locale

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am trying to populate Vaadin 8 Grid and one column has the type double. I am loading the Data into the table by combining it with a bean. I did it the following way,

Tasks bean:

```
public class Tasks{
    private int id;
    private Double duration;

    public StakeholderTasks(int i, String string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.taskName=taskName;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Double duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

TasksImpl:

```
public class stakeholderImpl extends CustomComponent {
    private Grid < Tasks > grid1;
    private Binder < Tasks > binder = new Binder < > (Tasks.class);
    cmpy = datastoreinstance.updateTaskList();
    provider1 = new ListDataProvider < > (cmpy);
    grid1 = new Grid < > ();
    grid1.addColumn(Tasks::getDuration);
    grid1.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event -> {

      form.setVisible(false);

      window = createWindow(window,
       ((MainUI)(UI.getCurrent())).getLanguageMessage("general.addnewtask"),
       event.getValue(), "EDIT", form);
     }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SQLException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }

 }

});

binder.forField(duration).asRequired(((MainUI)(UI.getCurrent())).getLanguageMessage("general.required"))
      .withValidator(new RegexpValidator(((MainUI)(UI.getCurrent())).getLanguageMessage("general.numerror"), DBConstants.regex))
      .bind(taskdetails -> nf_out.format(stakeholders.getDuration()),
      (taskdetails, formValue) -> 
      {
          NumberFormat nf_in = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
          double val = 0 d;
          try {
             val = nf_in.parse(formValue).doubleValue();
             taskdetails.setDuration(val);
          } catch (ParseException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
      }
  });
}
```

When I click on a row in the grid, then get the values from that row, load a form and then after save, show values in the grid. What I did in the binder for duration was validate the values for double based on `LOCALE.GERMANY` and else validate using `regex(regex= "[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1,2})?";)`

The problems I am facing are:

- I am gettign `.` instead of `,` for decimal notations in the grid (in the database it has `,`)
- When I click on the grid, the column Duration doubles the number of zeroes. For eg: if the value in the grid is 10.0 upon clicking on it, the value changes to 10000.00 or 1000.00. Is there a way to load the grid based on Locale for Germany?
- I know that I have not handled this correctly. Is there a better way to do this? Could someone just guide me through this. I am learning Vaadin now and I cannot get this working properly.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative and simple approach would be that instead you could use the [StringToDoubleConverter](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.1/com/vaadin/data/converter/StringToDoubleConverter.html) of the framework. By default it uses [NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale)](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/data/converter/AbstractStringToNumberConverter.java#L88) for number format. If you want something else than the default number format of your local, you can extend StringToDoubleConverter and override getFormat method to return customized [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html?is-external=true).